# Online Post-Apocalypse Generators & Aides

Tags: generator, post-apocalyptic

What are some good PostApoc generators and brainstorming aides?

There are lots of online generators for Swords & Sorcery worlds: you can find generators for dungeons, wandering monsters, settlements, treasures, races, terrain, coastlines, etc, but similar searches for ***post-apocalyptic*** generators turn up very little.

ETA: I realize this question is a little vague, but that's because I'm looking for *any kind* of PostApoc aides for general types of people, places, dangers and stuff.  I also think this thread could be a good resource for others in the future.

Many games have "wandering encounter" tables and "random finds" tables ("Aftermath" has some great tables for scavenging in the ruins, for instance), but they're geared toward a single session or a single location; they don't scale well.  This question is a system-agnostic attempt to find any existing aides (preferably online) for fleshing out ***large*** portions of a post-apocalyptic gameworld.

Comment: Generators for what specifically? Are you wanting to generate names, maps, or something else? I am concerned that _anything_ might be too broad, due to just attracting hugely disparate answers.

Comment: Do I understand right, if I summarise this as "Finding generators suited to fantasy is easy, where can I find generators that suit the post-apocalypse genre"?

Comment: Yes Seven, that's accurate to say, bearing in mind that I'm interested in tools for building up low or random detail over large areas, not high detail in small ones.

Comment: @AsIf If you're still after answers, I recommend you break this down into questions asking for post-apocalyptic generators for _specific things_ you're after: ask about post-apoc map generators into one question, and post-apoc people generators in another, etc. Just ask one at first though, so that if there's any trouble with your questions, we resolve that in _one_ of them - rather than possibly having to deal with the same issue in three or four!

Comment: Thanks y'all.  I think I've answered my own question, at least as far as I'm gonna get.  There's http://www.apocwords.net/systems/apocworld.html and there's some stuff in "Darwin's World" and "Aftermath!" that can help you prep a sandbox world.  A more narrativist approach is suggested by "Apocalypse: Emergence" by Paul Taliesin - http://ihousenews.pbworks.com/w/file/fetch/60537218/Apocalypse_Emergence.pdf - in which you use a *real* map but you alter the location descriptions just as the PCs get there.  Whole different approach but pretty cool.

Comment: Note: I have asked to reopen this question in order to turn my comment into an answer.  Hope I'm understanding this process correctly.